# Use sequent calculus to show if $\Gamma\vdash t_1=t_2$ then $\Gamma\vdash f(t_1)=f(t_2)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

Suppose the sequent $\Gamma\vdash t_1=t_2$ where $t_1,t_2$ are closed terms. Let $f$ be a one-place function symbol.

I am trying to find a sequent calculus derivation of $\Gamma\vdash f(t_1)=f(t_2)$ using these identity rules from [this set of notes](https://builds.openlogicproject.org/content/first-order-logic/sequent-calculus/sequent-calculus.pdf):

[image]

I don't see where functions fit in the picture.

Comment: I guess there is also a reflexivity rule of the form $\frac{}{\vdash t = t}$ for every closed term $t$ (note that there are no premises), otherwise there is no way to start a non-trivial sequent calculus proof concerning the identity $=$.

Comment: There may be something I'm missing, but I think those inferences are not meant in the usual way.  I think they may be intended to represent a partial replacement, e.g., not all the $t_1$s have to be replaced by $t_2$.  Both the question and the fact that they are equivalences rather than strict implications suggests this.

Comment: @DanielV - Indeed. For instance, in my answer below, the formula $\varphi(x)$ to which I applied the rule $=$ is $f(t_1) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever there is a non-trivial sequent to prove in the sequent calculus, use the cut rule, which is the only "intelligent" rule in that proof system.

The idea is that you can easily derive the sequent $t_1 = t_2 \vdash f(t_1) = f(t_2)$ by the rule $=$, and then you cut this sequent with your assumption $\Gamma \vdash t_1 = t_2$.

The formal solution is below, where the formula $\varphi(x)$ to which I applied the rule $=$ is $f(t_1) = f(x)$.

> !
> $$
> \dfrac{ \displaystyle{\atop \Gamma \vdash t_1 = t_2} \qquad
>   \dfrac{
>     \dfrac{
>       \dfrac{}{\vdash f(t_1) = f(t_1)}\text{refl}
>     }{
>       t_1 = t_2 \vdash f(t_1) = f(t_1)
>     }\text{w}_L
>   }
>   {
>     t_1 = t_2 \vdash f(t_1) = f(t_2)
>   }=
> }{
>   \Gamma \vdash f(t_1) = f(t_2)
> }\text{cut}
> $$